# Why does the HTML input with type "number" allow the letter 'e' to be entered in the field?

Tags: html, input, numbers

I have the following HTML5 input element:

```
<input type="number">
```

Why does this input allow for the character 'e' to be entered in the input field? No other alphabet character is able to be entered (as expected)

Using Chrome v. 44.0.2403.107

Example below to see what I mean.

```html
<input type="number">
```

Comment: It also allows you to enter +, -, and `.` multiple times in some browsers.

Comment: The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) warn about this and points to a [lengthy discussion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1398528) of the issue.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Because that's exactly how [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)) says it should work. The number input can accept [floating-point numbers](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-floating-point-number), including negative symbols and the `e` or `E` character (where the exponent is the number after the `e` or `E`):

> A floating-point number consists of the following parts, in exactly
>   the following order:
>
> 1. Optionally, the first character may be a "`-`" character.
> 2. One or more characters in the range "`0—9`".
> 3. Optionally, the following parts, in exactly the following order:
>
>    1. a "`.`" character
>    2. one or more characters in the range "`0—9`"
> 4. Optionally, the following parts, in exactly the following order:
>
>    1. a "`e`" character or "`E`" character
>    2. optionally, a "`-`" character or "`+`" character
>    3. One or more characters in the range "`0—9`".

Comment: I'm still baffled by this, first of all I'm not a mathematician, so what does "e" stand for in the context of a number? Second I don't get why input.value is an empty string as soon as you write an "e" in it, even though there are numbers and the character is allowed...

Comment: @Simon It's the exponent, you can see it in action if you multiply a large number by a large number and the calculator doesn't have enough supported digits to display it. Someone who is better at mathematics might explain it better.

Comment: @Simon, using the `e` is useful for condensing large numbers that would be otherwise tedious to type out. As a trivial example, `2e2 = 2*10^2 = 200`

Comment: Shouldn't the `input.value` then return `200` if you type in `2e2`?

Comment: @Simon depends whether the value is string or numeric value. If it's numeric, 2e2 *is* 200, those are equal values and it doesn't matter which form of presentation you use to display it, it's still 0b11001000 either way. If the input is string, then well, convert it to number first, so you don't have to bother which format was used to input the value.

Comment: @Ped7g Well that's exactly the problem! If I want to read out the value to find out it's `200` either way I can't, because `input.value` will return `undefined` as soon as I write the "e".

Comment: @Simon *"as soon as I write e"*, well, yes "4e" is not a number, while for example "4e+0" is a valid number (4). If you have some "live" client-side javascript code working with partial user input, you have to give user time to finish his input editing to provide full value, and not interfere half way into editing. If you have "undefined" from "4e+0" input, fix your "to number" parser. The example from question works well, reports "4e+1" as error, and "4e+0" is returned correctly as "4e+0" (ie. number between 1 and 5).

Comment: I just discovered this. I'm assuming the 'e' character is possibly used to indicate 'extension' for phone numbers since `type=tel` isn't commonly adopted

Comment: @Anthony No, `e` stands for Exponent.

Answer (score 103):

We can make it So simple like below

```html
<input type="number"  onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode == 69 ? false : true" />
```

Updated Answer

we can make it even more simple as @88 MPG suggests

```html
<input type="number" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" />
```

Comment: Better to use `return event.keyCode !== 69` as it avoids an unnecessary ternary operator. Also wouldn't recommend inlining.

Comment: This does not prevent copy-pasting `e` or `E` in the field though

Comment: are there any other instances similar to `e` or `E` that non-mathematicians might not be aware of that could be added to this conditional check?

Comment: @user1063287, this is the only exception in the case

Comment:  Final code: onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69 && event.keyCode !== 187 && event.keyCode !== 189" That prevents e, + and -.

Comment: @GTSJoe, you need to add 107 and 109 too, its ```+```, ```-``` on numpad :D

Comment: isnt there a built in configuration so disable this? no one eve uses "e" amazing how they preffered user experience of a few over the majority

Answer (score 57):

**The best way** to force the use of a number composed of digits only:

```html
<input type="number" onkeydown="javascript: return ['Backspace','Delete','ArrowLeft','ArrowRight'].includes(event.code) ? true : !isNaN(Number(event.key)) && event.code!=='Space'" />
```

### this avoids 'e', '-', '+', '.' ... all characters that are not numbers !

To allow number keys only, convert to number with `Number` function. If this is not a number, the result is NaN :

> isNaN(Number(event.key))

but accept Backspace, Delete, Arrow left, Arrow right :

> ['Backspace','Delete','ArrowLeft','ArrowRight'].includes(event.code)

This is for Firefox which allows spaces :

> event.code!=='Space'

Comment: Notice that this will be accepting space: the key of space is '  ', Number('  ') is equal to zero

Comment: adding && !event.key == ' '  solves the problem of spaces.

Comment: You missed 'Tab' there, preventing user using the Tab key to focus next input element.

Answer (score 36):

HTML input number type allows "e/E" because "e" stands for exponential which is a numeric symbol.

Example 200000 can also be written as 2e5. I hope this helps thank you for the question.

Answer (score 14):

```
<input type="number" onkeydown="return FilterInput(event)" onpaste="handlePaste(event)"  >

function FilterInput(event) {
    var keyCode = ('which' in event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;

    isNotWanted = (keyCode == 69 || keyCode == 101);
    return !isNotWanted;
};
function handlePaste (e) {
    var clipboardData, pastedData;

    // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text').toUpperCase();

    if(pastedData.indexOf('E')>-1) {
        //alert('found an E');
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Comment: How confident are you that this will prevent inserting an 'E' character with the copy and paste functionality?

Comment: Just checked, you are correct, it doesn't work for copy and pasted input.

Comment: You are correct @StephenKelzer. I added code to handle that.

Answer (score 11):

A simple solution to exclude everything but integer numbers

```html
<input  
    type="number"
    min="1" 
    step="1"
    onkeypress="return event.keyCode === 8 || event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

This solution does not prevent copy and pasting (including the letter 'e').

Comment: nice answer, but if I also want to allow decimal value in it. can you guide me.

Comment: To also allow decimal values I suggest taking a look at the answer of @yasarui

Answer (score 10):

To hide both letter `e` and minus sign `-` just go for:

```
onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69 && event.keyCode !== 189"
```

Answer (score 9):

## **[valueAsNumber](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#valueasnumber)** can do the job (copy/paste proof)

```html
    <input type="number" oninput="this.value = this.valueAsNumber">
```

Comment: It doesn't work if you type "1" and then paste "e123" after it.

Answer (score 8):

**Using angular, You can do this to restrict to enter e,+,-,E**

```
 <input type="number"  (keypress)="numericOnly($event)"/>


  numericOnly(event): boolean { // restrict e,+,-,E characters in  input type number
    debugger
    const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 101 || charCode == 69 || charCode == 45 || charCode == 43) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;

  }
```

Comment: this will restrict user to enter that character??

Comment: thanks for the help i was looking for the same solution in angular but now i have idea how to do it, i'll create directive and complete the task thanks for your post

Comment: you can create the directive that is best practice . as well you can also do directly in .ts file of your component!

Answer (score 8):

The E stands for the exponent, and it is used to shorten long numbers. Since the input is a math input and exponents are in math to shorten great numbers, so that's why there is an E.

It is displayed like this: 4e.

Links: [1](https://www.cyberdefinitions.com/definitions/E.html) and [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20180117122432/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57140.html)

Answer (score 5):

The above solutions work in regular html only.
For reactJS I would suggest you to do this instead

```
  <input type="number" onKeyDown={(e) =>["e", "E", "+", "-"].includes(e.key) && e.preventDefault()} >
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: Thanks. I was working in react and this is the only solution that worked for me. The remaining solutions don't work in react.

Comment: Doesn't work during copy paste, as it allows numbers with 'e' whilst copy paste.

Answer (score 3):

if you hit a key and its computer language equivalent is 69 it won't type it

```
<input
 type="number"
 onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69"
/>
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

## Angular; with IDE keyCode deprecated warning

The functionally is the same as rinku's answer but with IDE warning prevention

```js
numericOnly(event): boolean {
    // noinspection JSDeprecatedSymbols
    const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.key || event.keyCode;  // keyCode is deprecated but needed for some browsers
    return !(charCode === 101 || charCode === 69 || charCode === 45 || charCode === 43);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and standard solution : In Angular/ Js/ Ts you can use regular expression to restrict any input key.**

HTML: `<input type="text" name="input1" (keypress)="numericOnly($event)" />`

TS:

```
    numericPattern = /^[0-9]*$/;
    numericOnly(event){
       return this.numericPattern.test(event.key);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simplest solution is [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) .

```
<input type="number" onkeyup="this.value = parseInt(this.value); this.paste(this.onkeyup);"/>
```

ParseInt() returns blank(NaN) for E, e, +, -  and anything which is not a number.

Use `onkeyup` and `keydown` according to your convenience with `paste` event. For me `onkeyup` works best. This works with **copy-paste** as well

Answer (score -5):

```html
<input type="number" onkeydown="javascript: return ['Backspace','Delete','ArrowLeft','ArrowRight'].includes(event.code) ? true : !isNaN(Number(event.key)) && event.code!=='Space'" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is an exact copy of my answer without explanations! Your answer contributes nothing to the community!

Comment: You are an opportunist!