# Directive is ignored on input type number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working with AngularJS and one of the directives I implemented was to prevent the input of non-number characters, the implementation looks like this:

```
mainModule.directive('onlyNumbers', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/\D/g,'').replace(/ /g, '');
                if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This directive works fine when used on inputs of type `text` but if I want to use it on an input of type `number` the directive is ignored and it allows the entering of +,-,. and e characters, which are valid for an input number, but not valid for my scenario since I don't want to allow negative, decimal and the exponential number to be entered into these inputs of type number.

How can I make it so this directive has more priority than the one used on the input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the html input with type "number" allow the letter 'e' to be entered in the field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706611/why-does-the-html-input-with-type-number-allow-the-letter-e-to-be-entered-in)

Comment: by the way, the reason your Directive doesn't work is because angular already has a built in [Directive for `input[number]`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) that invalidates anything that sets the `ngModel` value to something other than a number (e.g. your Directive tries to treat the `number` as a `string`).

Comment: you *might* be able to solve this simply by changing your directive to `return Number(transformedInput);`

Comment: my question doesn't revolve around me not understanding the meaning of the number `e` in math so it's not a possible duplicate, I just want AngularJS to not ignore my directive, the `Number()` function didn't help my directive to be used by AngularJS.

Comment: as I said, angular isn't "ignoring" your directive; it is preventing your directive from updating `ng-model` due to the fact  that your directive changes the type of the `ng-model` value from a `number` to a `string`.

Comment: but even if I return `Number(transformedInput)` the directive is still not used, I need a way to make my directive to be used on inputs of type number.

Comment: just reproducing this directive shows that it clearly throws console errors, which should be helpful in finding a resolution.  when the `inputValue` is non-numeric, it is nullified by the angular input directive before your directive gets it, thus `Cannot read property 'replace' of null`.  When the value is numeric, there is no `.replace` function on the number prototype, so `inputValue.replace is not a function` makes sense.

Comment: using console.log to log the values in the directive shows that `e` is never sent to the browser alone;  it is sent along with the next value (i.e. `e5`) to determine the number of zeroes to pad the `ng-model` value with.  `-` and `+` are only sent if it prepends the number;  if they are sent in the middle of the number, the angular directive short circuits.

Comment: essentially, this directive is at odds with how the `number` input box functions in HTML, and even tricks like casting the input to a string and evaluating it before casting it back to a number won't work with this HTML element type.

Comment: for example, typing `1e4` in the input box results in a value `10000`; the `e` isn't actually part of the number until the number exceeds `1e20`.

Comment: I do not think that the question refers to how to validate the field or why it is accepting the 'e' character ...
I was trying to debug this on Chrome's dev tool and in fact, when 'e' char is typed, the breack point seems to be lost for some reason. It may be interesting to know why it is happening.

Comment: thank you, yes, that is indeed the topic of my question, I want for my directive to work when the input type is number, but whenever any of the accepted non-numeric characters is introduced, the directive is not being called