# All characters is not typed except e character in input tag with number attribute

Tags: html, input

I am using this `input` in one of form.why is it let user to type e character?.I am testing an web-application.

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" 
 placeholder="Enter Mobile" data-type="alphanum" />
```

Answer (score 3):

`e` is a valid mathematical number which equals to `2.718` to 3 decimal places.

Read more: [Mathematical constant e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))

Answer (score 1):

Because that's exactly how [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)) says it should work. The number input can accept [floating point numbers](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-floating-point-number), including negative symbols and the `e` or `E` character:

> A floating-point number consists of the following parts, in exactly
>   the following order:
>
> 1. Optionally, the first character may be a "`-`" character.
> 2. One or more characters in the range "`0—9`".
> 3. Optionally, the following parts, in exactly the following order:
>
>    1. a "`.`" character
>    2. one or more characters in the range "`0—9`"
> 4. Optionally, the following parts, in exactly the following order:
>
>    1. a "`e`" character or "`E`" character
>    2. optionally, a "`-`" character or "`+`" character
>    3. One or more characters in the range "`0—9`".

--

> [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706611/why-does-the-html-input-with-type-number-allow-the-letter-e-to-be-entered-in)