# Angular 8 Input validation accept only numbers

Tags: angular

I'm creating dynamic input field it will accept all type values. I need to restrict only numbers to be enter.

template:

```
<tr  *ngFor="let item of rowData">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let hitem of columnDefs" >
      <td *ngIf="!hitem.dropdown; else selectDrop">
        <span *ngIf="hitem.edit;else content">
          <div *ngIf="editing">
          <input [required]="required"  [name]="item[hitem.field]" [(ngModel)]="item[hitem.field]" />
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="!editing">
            {{item[hitem.field]}}
          </div>
        </span>
      <ng-template #content>content here... {{item[hitem.field]}} </ng-template>
      </td>
      <ng-template #selectDrop>
        <td>
          <select [(ngModel)]="item[hitem.field]">
            <option *ngFor="let item of aplAry">{{item}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </ng-template>
      </ng-container>
  </tr>
```

data:

```
mainHead = [{name:'', colspan:1}, {name:'Deatils', colspan:2}]
columnDefs = [
        {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make', edit:true },
        {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model', dropdown: true },
        {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price', edit:true}
];
aplAry = ['Celica','Mondeo','Boxter'];
    rowData = [
        { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
        { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
        { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
];
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4tdg9p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: use regex to validate

Comment: The answer marked as correct does not answer your question completely. You cannot enter a decimal and it would be very tedious to explicitly specify every single acceptable key code. Above all, it doesn't even apply to the specified input (`price`). I have added a concise solution for the same that does not require adding the key codes and works for decimal places.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand that last comment. What about testing 20 fields? Do you mean you don't want to specify each field in the directive? Either way I was just pointing out that the marked answer will lead to incorrect results but if it works fine for you then well and good.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create a custom directive for only `number`.
[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-only-numbers?file=src%2Fapp%2Fonlynumber.directive.ts)

> app.component.html

```
<input type="text" appOnlynumber/>
```

> onlynumber.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appOnlynumber]'
})
export class OnlynumberDirective {

  private navigationKeys = [
    'Backspace',
    'Delete',
    'Tab',
    'Escape',
    'Enter',
    'Home',
    'End',
    'ArrowLeft',
    'ArrowRight',
    'Clear',
    'Copy',
    'Paste'
  ];
  inputElement: HTMLElement;
  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
    this.inputElement = el.nativeElement;
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (
      this.navigationKeys.indexOf(e.key) > -1 || // Allow: navigation keys: backspace, delete, arrows etc.
      (e.key === 'a' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+A
      (e.key === 'c' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+C
      (e.key === 'v' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+V
      (e.key === 'x' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+X
      (e.key === 'a' && e.metaKey === true) || // Allow: Cmd+A (Mac)
      (e.key === 'c' && e.metaKey === true) || // Allow: Cmd+C (Mac)
      (e.key === 'v' && e.metaKey === true) || // Allow: Cmd+V (Mac)
      (e.key === 'x' && e.metaKey === true) // Allow: Cmd+X (Mac)
    ) {
      // let it happen, don't do anything
      return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if (
      (e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) &&
      (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)
    ) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const pastedInput: string = event.clipboardData
      .getData('text/plain')
      .replace(/\D/g, ''); // get a digit-only string
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, pastedInput);
  }

  @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
  onDrop(event: DragEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const textData = event.dataTransfer.getData('text').replace(/\D/g, '');
    this.inputElement.focus();
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, textData);
  }


}
```

Comment: Based on the condition how to add 'appOnlynumber' directive respective input field?

Comment: And also remember to declare the directive in the app.module.ts inside declarations! Good job!

Comment: the document.execCommand is showing deprecated, can you please suggest any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

To do it dynamically,

include **type** in `columnDefs`  objects:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srmeql?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
 columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "Make", field: "make", edit: true, type: "text" },
    { headerName: "Model", field: "model", dropdown: true, type: "text" },
    { headerName: "Price", field: "price", edit: true, type: "number" }
  ];
```

Template:

```
<input [required]="required" [type]="hitem.type" [name]="item[hitem.field]" [(ngModel)]="item[hitem.field]" />
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I can enter alphabets and digits

Comment: Ya.. i saw that, fixing it, meanwhile check demo 1

Comment: @Rijo Since in 2nd demo,type text or number was based om model value,  if we selected the whole text and deleted, the model value becomes blank, so it took text, deleted that part from the answer

Comment: I thought its browser dependency, I tried for other browser its not working :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201364/discussion-between-rijo-and-adrita-sharma).

Comment: Check this link for min/max : https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-4-min-max-validation

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve by using directive.

```
@Directive({
  selector: "input[numbersOnly]"
})
export class NumberDirective {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {}
  @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"])
  onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (
      // Allow: Delete, Backspace, Tab, Escape, Enter
      [46, 8, 9, 27, 13].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
      (e.keyCode === 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+A
      (e.keyCode === 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+C
      (e.keyCode === 86 && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+V
      (e.keyCode === 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+X
      (e.keyCode === 65 && e.metaKey === true) || // Cmd+A (Mac)
      (e.keyCode === 67 && e.metaKey === true) || // Cmd+C (Mac)
      (e.keyCode === 86 && e.metaKey === true) || // Cmd+V (Mac)
      (e.keyCode === 88 && e.metaKey === true) || // Cmd+X (Mac)
      (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39) // Home, End, Left, Right
    ) {
      return; // let it happen, don't do anything
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if (
      (e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) &&
      (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)
    ) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Show the directive in html,

```
 <input [required]="required" [name]="item[hitem.field]" [(ngModel)]="item[hitem.field]" numbersOnly/>
```

Declare the directive in AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent,NumberDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

**Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-allow-numbers-only-directive)**

### Update 1

If you like to allow numbers only in price field only:

```
<input [required]="required" [name]="item[hitem.field]" [(ngModel)]="item[hitem.field]" [numbersOnly]="hitem.headerName!='Make'"/>
```

and in directive,

```
export class NumberDirective {
  @Input() numbersOnly:boolean;
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {}
  @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"])
  onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(!this.numbersOnly)
      return;
    ....// rest of codes
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler approach using a directive.

```js
export class NumbersOnlyDirective {
    @Input('field') field;

    constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) { }

    @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInput(event): void {
        if (this.field === 'price') {
            const value = event.target.value;
            this.ngControl.control.setValue(parseFloat(value) || 0);
            if (value.slice(-1) === '.' && !value.slice(0, -1).includes('.')) {
                event.target.value = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This directive will only allow decimal numbers to be entered. `parseFloat` removes the alphabets and other special characters. I have used `|| 0` as a fallback in case the field is emptied but if you don't want anything to display, simply use `|| ''` instead. The `if` condition ensures that only one decimal point can be entered unlike when you use `type="number"` (`type="number"` will also change the `ngModel` to a string). The condition is placed after we update the `control` value so that if the last entered value is a `.`, the `ngModel` value will not include the `.` while the view will contain it.

Then use this directive in your template like below and pass the `field` value so that the this logic will only apply to the `price` field.

```html
<input [required]="required" numbersOnly [field]="hitem.field" [name]="item[hitem.field]" [(ngModel)]="item[hitem.field]" />
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-number-only-directive).

Comment: This is very clean option, thanks. I did have an issue with trying to capture zeroes immediately after the decimal point (eg, 31.001), so I swapped out the enitre `if (value.slice...` statement that handles the decimal point with a decimal regex value matching:  `event.target.value = (value.match(/\d+\.?\d*/g) || [null])[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Add `type="number"` in your input element

```
<input [required]="required"  [name]="item[hitem.field]" [(ngModel)]="item[hitem.field]" type="number" />
```

If you want to change input type dynamically then `[type]="type"` & in your .ts file set `type="text | number | email | tel, etc"`

Comment: How to limit maximum entry 5

Comment: set max="5" in input field

Comment: I tried max="5" but i can enter more digit even 'e' also

Comment: try this oninput="if(value > 5) value=5" in input tag

Comment: If you want to do it the angular way, then create a directive which sets input value to 5 if it exceeds the max value or you can use form control

Comment: For the 'e' problem you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706611/why-does-the-html-input-with-type-number-allow-the-letter-e-to-be-entered-in

Answer (score 0):

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[cdeCurrencyPipe]',
})
export class CDECurrencyPipe {
    private navigationKeys = ['Backspace','Delete','Tab','Escape','Enter','Home','End','ArrowLeft','ArrowRight','Clear','Copy','Paste'];
    @Input() OnlyNumber: boolean;
   
    constructor(private control : NgControl, 
            private elementRef: ElementRef,
            private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) { }

    @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])
    onBlur(raw) {
        if(raw && raw.length > 0){
            var strVal = raw.replace(/[$,]/g,"");
            this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(strVal);
        }
    }

    @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])
    onChange(raw) {
        if(raw && raw.length > 0){
            var strVal = raw.replace(/[$,]/g,"");
            this.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(strVal)
        }
    }

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (
            // Allow: Delete, Backspace, Tab, Escape, Enter, etc
            this.navigationKeys.indexOf(e.key) > -1 || // Allow: navigation keys: backspace, delete, arrows etc.
            (e.key === 'a' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.key === 'c' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+C
            (e.key === 'v' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+V
            (e.key === 'x' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+X
            (e.key === 'a' && e.metaKey === true) || // Allow: Cmd+A (Mac)
            (e.key === 'c' && e.metaKey === true) || // Allow: Cmd+C (Mac)
            (e.key === 'v' && e.metaKey === true) || // Allow: Cmd+V (Mac)
            (e.key === 'x' && e.metaKey === true) // Allow: Cmd+X (Mac)
            ) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (
            (e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) &&
            (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)
        ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follow:

**in component.html**

```
<input (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" type="text">
```

**in component.ts**

```
numberOnly(event): boolean {
  const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
       return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add validation like this

```
sufficient_observation_count: new FormControl( 0,[Validators.pattern("^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,100})$"),Validators.required])
```

The pattern will check that first digit shoud be whether 0 or from 1 to 9,and then subsequent 100 digits can be from 0 to 9,so it checks for decimals,negative numbers,exponentials etc.