# number input.value returns empty string if it contains "e" character

Tags: javascript, html

The example below is number input which if contains "e" character will return "" empty string when accessed with JavaScript.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.oninput = (e) => console.log(e.target.value)
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

Can you please explain the magic behind and possible way to prevent that from happening.

P.S: I am investigating the possibility to have input that will allow only [0-9] numbers on keyboard input/paste and will appreciate any suggestion on this topic :-)

Comment: `e` and `E` are valid floating point notation and therefore allowed in numeric inputs. E.g. `3.14e2`. If you absolutely must forbid them, then you'll need to weed them out yourself

Comment: @j08691 I was trying to weed before and ended up with the exact solution as Ritesh Khandekar suggests below, but replacing whole input value with an empty string doesn't seem like a nice UX, that's why wonder if there is a workaround it.

Comment: It happens with `input[type='number']` when the inputted number is not complete (i.e. invalid). For example, when `1e` is pasted then `e.target.value` contains the empty string, but when `1e2` is pasted then `e.target.value` contains `1e2`. It happens with all events (oninput, onchange, onkeydown, onkeyup, onkeypress) and it looks like this is general browser behavior that can't be changed.

Comment: The only exception I know is the `onpaste` event (`e.clipboardData.getData('text')` contains `1e` not empty string), but it's not easy to use in this case and doesn't cover all cases.

Comment: Just try with `e.target.valueAsNumber`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

e stands for exponential, it is a valid character for number. This is happening because you have set input type to number. You can try this

Please check this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31706796/5238397

Answer (score 1):

Remove other chars when inputted:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.oninput = (e) => {e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");}
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Ritesh I also tried this approach initially and ended up with previous value being replaced with an empty string which isn't the desired output for the case I am working with. But thank you anyway for your help :-)