# Modify the numeric input to accept only numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a input of number type of my HTML page. This is very close to this one 
[example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number). 
Unfortunately this input accepts values like '---', '+++', 'eee' and other non-numeric input.

My task is disable the ability of the control to enter non-numerics like '----'.

Also possible to show a error message when user haves the form. Is any way to do that?

Comment: add javascript onChange event and do validation over there.

Comment: Use regular expression and validate the input on the input event @sluge

Answer (score 4):

If you specify the input type as number it won't accept non-numeric characters

KEYCODE 8 and 46 are to allow backspace and delete.

Try inputting non-numeric characters in the text box below

```html
<input type="number" onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46 ? true : !isNaN(Number(event.key))" />
```

Comment: How else would you allow negative nos? Also e stands for exponent that's why it is allowed.

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706611/why-does-the-html-input-with-type-number-allow-the-letter-e-to-be-entered-in/31706796 to understand better

Comment: If you stiil don't want them try the updated answer

Comment: Glad, I wad able to help:)

Comment: Not my question though :P

Comment: I just noticed that;)