# <input type="number"> does not prevent the invalid numbers inputting, but "element.value" does not allow me to correct them

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) about `<input type="number">`:

> They include built-in validation to reject non-numerical entries.

Does it mean "reject when try to submit the HTML form"?
I inputted "4e4--23". HTML has not rejected it.

[image]

Therefore, `<input type="number">` **can not prevent** the **inputting** of non-number value.
I don't care about I it if I can programically correct user's input.
For example, user inputted the minus sign not in the first position - using JavaScript, *theoretically* I can remove it.

However here is unobvious JavaScript behavior: when input element
has "number" attribute and `value` is invalid number, `Element.value` returns
an empty string. It's very tricky programmatic validation: because we
have empty string value, the validator will return "The input must not be empty. Please input the value." error while input in not empty!

```js
document.getElementById("target").addEventListener("input", blackbox => {
 console.log(document.getElementById("target").value);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" value="" id="target">
```

How can I get the actual inputted value? (If you know Vue, please add the solution for Vue, too.)

Comment: can u check with <form> tag?

Comment: @Antony Thank you for the response. My answer: generally - no. I will not wrap every my component to `form`.

Comment: You can use the `<input>.checkValidity()` to know if the value is correct, or else, use an input type text, and filter his `value` to match numbers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706611/why-does-the-html-input-with-type-number-allow-the-letter-e-to-be-entered-in

Comment: I don't think browsers validate on input, only when submitting. So a user can put anything in the input field, including complete words. If you need checking on input, you'll have to write your own script.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```html
I only accept numbers:
<input type="text" v-model="form.availability" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');">
<br>
I only accept numbers inlcuding a point:
<input type="text" v-model="form.availability" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
<br>
EDIT: I accept negative numbers inlcuding a point:
<input type="text" v-model="form.availability" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
<br>
EDIT: I accept negative numbers inlcuding a point:
<input type="text" v-model="form.availability" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
<br>
EDIT2: I accept negative numbers inlcuding a point (only one "minus" sign):
<input type="text" v-model="form.availability" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1').replace(/(\-.*)\-/g, '$1');">
<br>
EDIT3: I also accept "e" and "E"
<input type="text" v-model="form.availability" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.\-\e\E]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1').replace(/(\-.*)\-/g, '$1').replace(/(\e.*)\e/g, '$1').replace(/(\E.*)\E/g, '$1');">
<br>
```

Different browsers treat the "input type number" differently

Comment: This doesn't allow for negative numbers

Comment: Added a new input that allows for negative numbers

Comment: yeah but now you can have `47-----7`

Comment: added another that only allows for 1 negative, the regex needs to be tweaked to only allow it on the beginning (this method also works on firefox)

Comment: sorry for nitpicking but this also needs to be able to support scientific notation with uppercase and lowercase 'e'

Comment: added "e" and "E" but they can co-exist, this regex could be a lot tidier, but I'm not the best "regexer" : \

Answer (score 0):

Try `<input type="number" inputmode="numeric">` or `<input type="tel" inputmode="numeric">`

Comment: `inputmode="numeric"` is not supported by Safari and only after explicitly been enabled in Firefox.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but looks like it does not work even in chrome. I inputted your solution to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96qby0rk/1/). Please try to input something like `4-6-5--` - it will not be prevented.

Comment: that's because the minus character is allowed in numbers. Admittedly, it should appear only once, but you should be liberal about user input editing before eventually validating the input, either on submit or perhaps when the input loses focus, rather than micromanaging every keystroke

Answer (score 0):

There is workaround in Vue.js. You can use **$event.target** which has more details. It contains object **'validity'** whose properties **'badInput'** tells us if value is not correct.

See example bellow, for wrong value like **'e23', '--1**' we will get **'NaN'** which can be use in validation rules.

```js
Vue.component('input-element', {
    template: ' <input :type="type" :value="inputValue" @input="onInput($event.target)" />',
    props: {
        type: String,
        value: String | Number | Boolean
    },
    computed: {
        inputValue: {
            get() {
                if (this.type == 'number') {
                    return !isNaN(this.value) ? this.value : '';
                }

                return this.value;
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onInput(eventTarget) {
            let value = eventTarget.value;

            if (this.type == 'number' && eventTarget.validity?.badInput) {
                value = eventTarget.valueAsNumber;
            }

            this.$emit('input', value);
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        numberValue: 0
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input-element type="number" v-model="numberValue"></input-element> 
  <div>{{ numberValue }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will still permit numbers that translate to whole numbers, such as `1E1`