# Does attribute value "number" of "input" tag is critical for accessibility?

Tags: html, accessibility

The attribute `number` of `input` causes confusing during JavaScript validation and input filtration (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718093/input-type-number-does-not-prevent-the-invalid-numbers-inputting-but-eleme)). I am considering to use `text` attribute value (however with `inputmode="numeric"`) when expect the numeric input from users. I see only one obstacle for now: accessibility. Does `text` value for numeric input fields impacts on accessibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any special accessibility problems with this approach - as long as the user is adequately informed about any 'bad' input (in line with the [WCAG 3.3.x success criteria](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/input-assistance)).

At a minimum, you should direct users to the specific field that has the erroneous input, and preferably give a clue what is wrong with it ("this field must contain only numbers"), rather than just reporting a blanket "this form is not filled out correctly".

Using `inputmode="numeric"` is a good ergonomic choice, and should prevent bad input from happening in those user agents that handle this attribute correctly.

You'll still have to convert the string to a numerical value later, of course.