# JS added zeros to decimal ad end

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning,

I would like to use JavaScript to manipulate a number input field so that if only one decimal place is entered, a zero is added, and if no decimal place is given, even two.

Now I have tried the following:

```
///html

<input type="number" id="netpricePerSeat" name="netpricePerSeat" placeholder="0,00" step=".01" min="2.5" onchange="endingZeros(this)" onkeyup="endingZeros(this)" onclick="endingZeros(this)" pattern="[0-9]+([\,|\.][0-9]+)?">


///js
  function endingZeros(input) {
    var countDecimals = function(value) {
      if (Math.floor(value) !== value)
        if(value.toString().includes('.'))
          return value.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0;
        if(value.toString().includes(','))
          return value.toString().split(",")[1].length || 0;
      return 0;
    }

    if(!isNaN(input.value) && countDecimals(input) === 1) {
      input.value = input.value + '0';
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately it is not clear at all.
Important, in the field you should be able to enter decimal with comma or dot, because the form should be for all countries

Comment: sounds like you should not be using `"type="number"`

Comment: look in the code, I already use it.

Comment: guessing you missed the "**not**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should remove your handler from the `onkeyup` event, because it doesn't allow the user to enter the second decimal character.

Then take into account that `<input type="number" />` allows you to enter the characters "e", "-" and "_" as well (according to the spec, see [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31706796))

Try this one:

```js
function endingZeros(input) {
    if (!isValidInput(input)) {
        return;
    }

    const decimalsCount = countDecimals(input.value);

    if (decimalsCount === 0) {
        input.value = input.value + '.00';

        return;
    }

    if (decimalsCount === 1) {
        input.value = input.value + '0';

        return;
    }

    return;

    function countDecimals(val = '') {
        const formattedVal = String(val).replace(/,/, '.');

        if (Number.isInteger(formattedVal)) {
            return 0;
        }

        return formattedVal.match(/\.(\d+)/)?.[1]?.length || 0;
    }

    function isValidInput(node) {
        return node && !Number.isNaN(node.value)
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="netpricePerSeat" name="netpricePerSeat" placeholder="0,00" step=".01" min="2.5" onchange="endingZeros(this)" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69 && event.keyCode !== 187 && event.keyCode !== 189" pattern="[0-9]+([\,|\.][0-9]+)?">
```

Comment: It runs perfectly, but how could I add two zeros, when I only input 1 number, like this `8 => 8,00`