# Error in validation of numeric field in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

I have a problem with the validation of a number type field where the identification of a person must be placed, my data annotations is this

```
 [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "El RUT es Obligatorio")]
 [RegularExpression("(^[0-9]+$)", ErrorMessage = "Solo se Permiten Números")]
 [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "El RUT solo permite 10 dígitos")]
```

[image]

This is my view of Register

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>RUT Paciente:</label>
    <input asp-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_RUT" type="number" placeholder="RUT" class="form-control" autofocus />
    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_RUT" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

The error is when I put the letter e, it is the only letter that allows me to enter both uppercase and lowercase.

How can I correctly validate this field?

Comment: The attributes are defined correctly. Therefore, show the view content. The problems in there.

Comment: Double check the question, I put the view of my registration page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following post: [Why does the html input with type “number” allow the letter 'e' to be entered in the field?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31706611/6630084)

This answer why your `<input>` accept the 'e' letter. But, it goes without saying, the MVC validation reject it.

The post does not contain data model definition. Therefore, I am improvising...

I called data model class as `DataModel`:

```cs
public class DataModel
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "El RUT es Obligatorio")]
    [RegularExpression("(^[0-9]+$)", ErrorMessage = "Solo se Permiten Números")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "El RUT solo permite 10 dígitos")]
    public string PAC_RUT { get; set; }
}
```

And used `HtmlHelper` to generate the HTML:

```
@model DataModel
    
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PAC_RUT)
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PAC_RUT, htmlAttributes: new { type="number", autofocus = "autofocus" })</p>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PAC_RUT)
</div>
   ...
```

And this is the `.cshtml` compiled to the HTML. So, as you can see when using the `HtmlHelper`, the generated HTML that including set of additional  attributes allowing to enter only 10 digits:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="PAC_RUT">PAC_RUT</label>
    <p><input class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-length="El RUT solo permite 10 d&#xED;gitos" data-val-length-max="10" data-val-regex="Solo se Permiten N&#xFA;meros" data-val-regex-pattern="(^[0-9]&#x2B;$)" data-val-required="El RUT es Obligatorio" id="PAC_RUT" name="PAC_RUT" type="number" value="" /></p>
    <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="PAC_RUT" data-valmsg-replace="true">El RUT es Obligatorio</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's for you help.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem of the letter 'e' , i use a script en el event onkeypress="return Solo Numeros(event); of my input

```
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>RUT Paciente:</label>
    <input asp-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_RUT" type="number" placeholder="RUT" onkeypress="return SoloNumeros(event);" class="form-control" autofocus />
    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_RUT" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>
```

I put here the script code

```
function SoloNumeros(e) {
        var keynum = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
        if ((keynum == 8 || keynum == 48))
            return true;
        if (keynum <= 47 || keynum >= 58) return false;
        return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
    }
```