# Why does HTML input type number accepts the + and - symbol?

Tags: html

Input type number accepts `+` and `-`.
I don't want this behavior. How can I prevent this?

```
<input type="number">
```

I can type 100+ or 200- or both 300+-
maybe some other special characters are acceptable. I don't want this. Number input should only be Number.

Is it possible User should not even type any special characters?

Comment: Because numbers can be positive or negative

Comment: What if I don't want this?

Comment: @HasiburRahman then you validate the input.

Comment: Don't forget that the number input also accepts `e` and `E` as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31706796/616443

Comment: @HasiburRahman you'd need to implement such validation using `JavaScript` and that will depend on what chars you'd allow besides numbers.

Comment: Stick with text input if you want that kind of control. See [HTML text input allow only numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469357/215552)

Answer (score 4):

The default behaviour of a number input is to allow the user to type anything they like and perform validation *when the form is submitted*.

This is consistent with how all other validation features built into HTML forms work.

If you type *100-* then try to submit the form, the submission will fail and an prompt along the lines of "Please type a number" will appear.

If you want validate-as-you-type behaviour then you will need to implement it with JavaScript. This is tricky to pull off well though. For example, you might prevent a user from pasting a string copied from a document like `123,456.12` because it has a comma in it. If you let them paste it they can then edit the comma out.